# Starting Apache as service quits with SIGWINCH

Tags: systemd, apache-httpd, services, signals, suse

When running `service apache start` I see in the log file this entry:

```
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 1906:tid XXX] AH00489: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
                         OpenSSL/1.0.2g PHP/7.0.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] [pid 1906:tid XXX] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 1906:tid XXX] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

and the service `apache` does not start? I can find in internet what `SIGWINCH` means [`Window size change`] but it does not really help me in this case.

The file `/etc/systemd/system/apache.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache Webserver [FaF Compiled]
After=network.target nss-lookup.target time-sync.target
Before=getty@tty1.service plymouth-quit.service xdm.service

[Service]
Type=notify
PrivateTmp=true
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd -k start
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd -k graceful
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/httpd -k graceful-stop
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=httpd.service apache.service
```

Running on SLES 12 SP1. I have compiled Apache on my own. Starting it with `apachectl -k start` works perfectly and I can access and run the PHP code.

**My question:**
What am I doing wrong that the `apache` service does not start. I have enabled it with `systemctl enable apache`. This was the output:

```
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service' '/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service'
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service' '/etc/systemd/system/apache.service'
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service'
```

Comment: How were `SIGWINCH` made fatal? The default action is to discard the signal.

Answer (score 3):

`systemd` is instructing Apache to stop with `graceful-stop`, which generates a `SIGWINCH` signal, and hence the log `caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully`. (the `SIGWINCH` signal is (ab)used by Apache)

IMO, there is a possibility of another error, including configuration errors, making it stop, and you are looking at related symptoms which are normal behaviour.

I would recommend perusing your Apache error logs, usually by default in SLES under the directory `/var/log/apache2`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem reported on [RedHat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1212224). Closed with a status "NOTABUG". Eventually recognised as wrong config.

img #1
[image: 1]

---

img #2
[image: 2]

---

img #3
[image: 3]

---

#### UPDATE

I found one more similar problem reported on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/786876/apache-wont-start-on-centos-7). And one more in the answer to it, in the image below.

img 1/1[image]

Comment: `-DFOREGROUND` does not help in my case. Apache does start but it does not return back to `service` and therefore `service` complains with `apache2.service start operation timed out. Terminating.`

Comment: Did you read the thread in the link?

Comment: I gave up. I understand the situation but I don't have a clue how to fix it. I found out when I remove `ExecReload=` from `/usr/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service` then `SIGWINCH` is not sent but then Apache does not start - no error message in log, nothing. It just immediately quits when it has been started. I implemented now the hack that I run `apachectl -k start` as a cron job when the system starts. I can restart Apache with `apachectl -k restart`. I will try it later; may be I get some new ideas.

Comment: I found one more, different. See update.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment on the [Red Hat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1212224#c16) linked from [Tomasz's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302117/22812):

> It looks like you need to run 00-systemd.conf if you want systemd to recognize that httpd has started successfully.

I ran this and it worked:

```
ln -sr /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-systemd.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/00-systemd.conf
systemctl restart httpd
```

I'm on Amazon Linux 2 (will probably also work on RHEL/Centos 7).

Comment: Thanks for giving credit, but, … where did you get this?

Comment: @G-Man I've edited this answer to correctly attribute that quote.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is from adding too many domains at once.
You are supposed to add one domain then restart httpd. 
I made this mistake too.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on _why_ this fixes the problem?

Comment: I hate apache so much if this is the issue.  I just have 7 vHosts.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue happening in AWS Cloud9 Console.  I thought that `SIGWINCH` by itself was the problem, but later found a default setting in AWS Cloud 9 that terminates the instance after 30 minutes. This triggers `SIGWINCH`, which then tells Apache to shut down.

I had no idea about this, and this took me 2 days to figure out.  I hope it saves someone time.

[image: Be sure to adjust the "Stop my environment" setting]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).